# Django view in array

Tags: django, templates, view

I have 2 tables (posts, upvoted) that I am working within and am looking to see if a post has been upvoted already and if it has, replace the upvote arrow with a filled arrow. In my view, I am already sending over the Upvote object to my template and am trying to check if the post.id exists within the upvoted table. I tried the code below but it didn't work. How would I do it?

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default="onebyone.png", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post_karma = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} - {self.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} - {self.body[:30]}"


class Upvoted(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="upvoted", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="upvoted", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upvoted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.user.username} - {self.post.user.username} - {self.post.body[:30]}")
```

View:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    # form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    # if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        img = form.cleaned_data["image"]
        body = form.cleaned_data["body"]
        if img is None:
            img = "images/onebyone.png"
        post = Post.objects.create(user=request.user, image=img, body=body)
        post.save()
        return redirect("posty:dashboard")

    sorting = request.GET.get("sort")
    ordering = {
        "date_sort": "-created_at",
        "karma_sort": "-post_karma",
        "comment_sort": "-comment_count",
        None: "-created_at",
    }
    # followed_posts = Post.objects.filter(
    #     user__profile__in=request.user.profile.follows.all()
    # ).order_by("-created_at")

    followed_posts = Post.objects.filter(
        user__profile__in=request.user.profile.follows.all()
    ).order_by(ordering[sorting])

    # get current date_time
    now = datetime.now()

    return render(
        request,
        "posty/dashboard.html",
        {"form": form, "posts": followed_posts, "comment": Comment, "now": now, "upvote" : Upvoted, "downvote" : Downvoted},)
```

```
{% if post.id in upvote.post_id.all %}
```

Comment: Show us your models and your view please.

Comment: Do you also have any `Profile` model? Share entire `dashboard` view you should also maintain separate if conditions for both the requests i.e. GET and POST.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't send your Model objects in context, you must do the queries in your view, then send the results to context.

Second:
You can use `annotate()` and `Exists()` for that.

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

followed_posts = (
    Post.objects.filter(    
        user__profile__in=request.user.profile.follows.all()
    )
    .annotate(
        is_liked_by_user=Exists(
            Upvoted.objects.filter(post_id=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user)
        )
    )
    .order_by(ordering[sorting])
)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if post.is_liked_by_user %}
 ... put whatever you want here.
{% endif %}
```